# Hangs when executing subprocess.Popen('su', shell=True)

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I apologize if this is a repeat question, I tried searching the web, but most people use sudo.

However, I can't use sudo, I can use 'su' to login as root. I'm executing the following code:

```
try:
    p_su = subprocess.Popen('su', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    out_su, err_su = p_su.communicate()
    # >>> The program hangs here. <<<
except:
    print "Unable to login as root (su). Consult the Software Engineer."
    sys.exit()

print out_su
if "Password" in out_su:
    try:
        p_pw = subprocess.Popen('password', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        out_pw, err_pw = p_pw.communicate()
    except:
        print "Unable to login as root (password). Consult the Software Engineer."
        sys.exit()
```

At the point noted above the program hangs for at least 30+ minutes. When I run "su" in the linux terminal it takes a second or two, sometimes less.

Comment: It _maybe_ hangs as `su` try to interact with the user on the console (_tty_) ? On the other hand, on my Linux system, `su` aborts when _stdin_ is not connected to a _tty_: `echo echo | su` => `su: must be run from a terminal`

Comment: You're probably going to need to use [`pexpect`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for this.

Comment: Does pexpect come with Python-2.7.5? If not, then I can't use it.

Comment: Sylvain, I'm not exactly sure what you're talking about, when you say, "console (tty)" what are you referring to? (Sorry, I'm new to Linux and Python)

Comment: Essentially `su` is an interactive prompt, exactly like a login. Because of this the command never actually has a return code and as such it never truly "finishes" the command. This is why it hangs and why you can't wait until it is completed and then send a password. The only ways around this are to use an expect module like `pexpect` or to run the python program with elevated `su` privileges so a password isn't required to run whatever command follows.

Comment: Tell us more about what you are trying to acheive. Perhaps there is an easier way.

Comment: So, Thimble, basically you're telling me that I can't use subprocess.Popen because it doesn't have interactive capabilities? If that's the case, then write that as an answer, since that makes sense.

Comment: I'm trying to streamline an install process. I need to do some stuff with a tar (not as root) then login as root and install the package without any user interaction, other than running the python script/program.

Comment: Then perhaps this will work better for you: `p_su = Popen(['su', '-c', 'install_program'])`, and `p_su.communicate('my_password')`.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of the hang, `su` is waiting for you to type your password. It is not hung, it is patiently waiting.

If you are running this program from a command line (like `python my_program.py`), try typing a line of nonsense and hitting return. I expect that `err_su` will have content like this:

```
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Comment: It depends upon what you are trying to do. Invoking `su` is one step toward some greater goal. What is the greater goal?

Answer (score 0):

Is that sufficient?

```
import subprocess
p_su = subprocess.Popen('su', shell=True).communicate()
```

I don't know the exact reason, but there is a note [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) which tells:

> Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function as that can deadlock based on the child process output volume. Use Popen with the communicate() method when you need pipes.

The note apparently holds for many of the subprocess methods.

Comment: Not quite, remember, I need to enter the password. I tried that too, but I wasn't sure how to verify the output lines to determine whether or not to enter a password or something else.

Comment: I'm not able to capture the return value neither, maybe expect/pexpect is a better approach in the end!

Comment: I'm trying to get expect/pexpect to work now, its giving me a better response. :) We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, @Thimble 's comment below my question is correct.

Therefore, since `subprocess.Popen` will not provide the output I desire I need to do the following:

```
try:
    child = pexpect.spawn("su")
expect:
    print "Unable to login as root. Consult the Software Engineer."
    sys.exit()

i = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, "Password:"])

if i == 0
    print "Timed out when logging into root. Consult the Software Engineer."
    sys.exit()
if i == 1
    child.sendline("password")
    print "Logged in as root"
    sys.exit()
```

I hope this helps someone else!